# how to use rest srvice in apache apache-nifi?

Tags: xml, rest, groovy, apache-nifi

- How can i get rest response in apache -nifi and parse it into xml
  ,can you recommend me any tutorials,articles or examples,i am
  completely new at nifi?

---

Comment: Please read carefully [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page to see what kind of things StackOverflow is a best place for. You will also find examples of questions that don't fit best SO.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache NiFi REST API is well defined and documented in the [API Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html). Responses will be provided in JSON, and you can use any number of tools to convert JSON into XML (including, coincidentally, NiFi itself via the *record processing* tools and a combination of `JsonPathReader` and `ScriptedRecordSetWriter` with Groovy's XML capabilities).

NiFi's user interface is also a consumer (and essentially the reference implementation of a consumer) of the REST API, so with your browser open to NiFi, you can use the Developer Tools to monitor the underlying API requests and responses as you perform tasks in the UI in order to become more familiar with the operations.